# Is it possible to set the number of rows in a Power BI Small Multiples grid to a variable?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want a visual comparison of stacked histograms using the same x-axis scale. In this situation, I don't always have the same number of histograms for each dataset.

I would like to do a small multiples grid in Power BI that is *N* rows by 1 column; where *N* is the number of instruments that are collecting data for the client site selected in a Slicer. Some clients may be collecting data with one instrument.  Other clients may use 3 or more instruments.

Is there a way to set the number of rows to a variable in a small multiples grid or would it be possible to embed a chart in a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The default is a 2×2 grid of small multiples, but you can adjust the number of rows and columns to up to 6×6. Any multiples that don’t fit on that grid will load in as you scroll down.

You can adjust the style and position of the small multiple titles in the Small multiple title card:
And you can change the dimensions of the grid in the Grid layout card:

Comment: You can actually use one column.  Just set the number of columns to one.  It would be useful if the number of rows could be a variable.

Comment: Did you mean to include code or images? You have colons that appear to be leading to something, but then there's nothing there.